# Controller handler method supported return types

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

While learning the Spring framework, I notice in the book *Spring in Action*, the author doesn't use `ModelandView` method return type in controllers. The author is declaring the controller methods as return type of `String` and the return clause in the method is just returning a string such as `return "/views/theview";`

Can someone elaborate the internal differences of how this works?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I want the internal implementation details regarding differences in the (old) spring 2.0 and (new) spring 3.0 ways of doing the same thing.

Comment: I've given an answer for 3.2+. Larry Z has posted an answer for version prior to 3.2. What you can also do is make a Controller method, put a breakpoint inside it, then debug. Look at the stack trace once you're inside to see the classes involved. You can then return from your method to see where it goes to handle the return type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an in depth look.

Spring offers a `DispatcherServlet` class that, typically, handles all your requests. It does this in its `doDispatch(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)` method

```
// Actually invoke the handler.
mv = ha.handle(processedRequest, response, mappedHandler.getHandler());
```

where `mv` is the final `ModelAndView` object, `ha` is a wrapper to your controller method annotated with `@RequestMapping`.

This will usually go through a stack of method calls ending up at `ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle`

```
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch
```

Looking at the source

```
public final void invokeAndHandle(ServletWebRequest webRequest,
                ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, Object... providedArgs) throws Exception {

    Object returnValue = invokeForRequest(webRequest, mavContainer, providedArgs);

    setResponseStatus(webRequest);

    if (returnValue == null) {
        if (isRequestNotModified(webRequest) || hasResponseStatus() || mavContainer.isRequestHandled()) {
            mavContainer.setRequestHandled(true);
            return;
        }
    } else if (StringUtils.hasText(this.responseReason)) {
        mavContainer.setRequestHandled(true);
        return;
    }

    mavContainer.setRequestHandled(false);

    try {
        this.returnValueHandlers.handleReturnValue(returnValue, getReturnValueType(returnValue), mavContainer, webRequest);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
            logger.trace(getReturnValueHandlingErrorMessage("Error handling return value", returnValue), ex);
        }
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

`returnValue` is the object returned by your `@RequestMapping` method. It goes through

```
this.returnValueHandlers.handleReturnValue
```

where Spring determines a `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` to handle that object.

```
public void handleReturnValue(
        Object returnValue, MethodParameter returnType,
        ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest)
        throws Exception {

    HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler handler = getReturnValueHandler(returnType); // returns the appropriate handler
    Assert.notNull(handler, "Unknown return value type [" + returnType.getParameterType().getName() + "]");
    handler.handleReturnValue(returnValue, returnType, mavContainer, webRequest);
}
```

`getReturnValueHandler(returnType);` returns the appropriate handler. The [`HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler.html) is an interface with a `supportsReturnType` method that returns `true` if the handler supports that type (`String`, `View`, `ResponseEntity`, [etc. (look for supported return types)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)). So the method returns the first handler it finds that supports that type and runs it.

Spring, at initialization, registers a whole slew of implementations of `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`. Basically all the [known implementing classes in its javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler.html#supportsReturnType%28org.springframework.core.MethodParameter%29).

For example, if you return a String, Spring will use a [`ViewNameMethodReturnValueHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ViewNameMethodReturnValueHandler.html) to handle the response.

Now, which return type to use is up to you. If you wanted to return a `Model` so you can use request attributes in your jsp view, you can either have Spring pass a `Model` instance to your method or you can create the `Model` object yourself and pass it to a `ModelAndView` which your return. It's a matter of style in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Functionality wise there is no difference, both these are equivalent:

```
@RequestMapping(..)
public String requestMapping1(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("attr1", attr1);
    return "viewName";
}

@RequestMapping(..)
public ModelAndView requestMapping2(){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("viewName");
    modelAndView.addObject("attr1", attr1);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

However the preferred approach is the former and that is the reason why the author has not used the latter in the book samples.

Answer (score 0):

In spring source code, you can see this class `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`. In the method   `public ModelAndView getModelAndView(...)`, you can get how sping-mvc generate `ModelAandView` object.

```
if (returnValue instanceof HttpEntity) { // returnValue is returned Value of Handler method
            handleHttpEntityResponse((HttpEntity<?>) returnValue, webRequest);
            return null;
        }
        else if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(handlerMethod, ResponseBody.class) != null) {
            handleResponseBody(returnValue, webRequest);
            return null;
        }
        else if (returnValue instanceof ModelAndView) {
            ModelAndView mav = (ModelAndView) returnValue;
            mav.getModelMap().mergeAttributes(implicitModel);
            return mav;
        }
        else if (returnValue instanceof Model) {
            return new ModelAndView().addAllObjects(implicitModel).addAllObjects(((Model) returnValue).asMap());
        }
        else if (returnValue instanceof View) {
            return new ModelAndView((View) returnValue).addAllObjects(implicitModel);
        }
        else if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(handlerMethod, ModelAttribute.class) != null) {
            addReturnValueAsModelAttribute(handlerMethod, handlerType, returnValue, implicitModel);
            return new ModelAndView().addAllObjects(implicitModel);
        }
        else if (returnValue instanceof Map) {
            return new ModelAndView().addAllObjects(implicitModel).addAllObjects((Map) returnValue);
        }
        else if (returnValue instanceof String) { // String is here, return new ModelAndView
            return new ModelAndView((String) returnValue).addAllObjects(implicitModel);
        }
```

So in this method you can learn that spring-mvc can handle many returned types of handler method to build ModleAndView object.

Comment: Note that this class has been deprecated since 3.2

Comment: Thank you for your reminding. I think I will upgrade spring version to 3.2.x

Comment: OP seems to want to know implementations since 2.0 so this is still a valid answer.