# Why do I need to add @ResponseBody to my controller action?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

According to [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html), this annotation indicates that a method return value should be bound to the web response body. I understand that, and I've been using this for my ajax calls. However, I recently came across code that doesn't use the annotation.

So I guess my question really is why it works without the annotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the annotation, a different process takes place. Depending on the return type ([you can find the defaults in this document](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-return-types)) the response will be generated differently.

For example, if your return type is `String`, then, by default, the return value will be resolved as a `View` name, a `ViewResolver` will try to resolve and create a `View` object, and a `RequestDispatcher` will forward/include/redirect to it (ex. a `jsp`) so that the `Servlet` container can handle generating the response.

The actual interface that handles the return type is `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` and there are many implementations for each type. [See here for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242454/controller-handler-method-supported-return-types).

Comment: In both cases, the return type is ModelAndView.

Comment: Alternatively, you can return `void` and inject a `PrintWriter` to your controller method and write the response body to the stream. It effectively results in the **similar** behavior.

Comment: @abcXYZ See my edit and the linked answer. There's a special handler for `ModelAndView`. If you have both `@ResponseBody` and are returning a `ModelAndView`, it depends which handler has priority.

Comment: @abcXYZ If you look at the implementation of `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`, `ModelAndView` has priority, ie. comes up earlier in a `List` of `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` instances.

Comment: The reason why I asked was because it seems like in the case without the @ResponseBody annotation, I would sometimes get `IllegalStateException:STREAM` when trying to get the writer. Any thoughts on this? Or it's a complete separate issue?

Comment: @abcXYZ Not without seeing what you were trying to do. It's obviously related, but separate.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I updated my question and accepted your answer for the original question I asked.

Comment: @abcXYZ Try asking a new question with full details if it's still an issue.